# How to get the transformed HTML code resulted from firefox?

Tags: firefox

```
<html>x<body><div>abc</div></html>
```

Firefox transforms the above code to the following.

```
<html><head></head><body>x<div>abc</div></html>
```

Is there a command line for me to get this transformed result from input HTML code taken from stdin? I assume that javascript and CSS are not effective if they are in the HTML code.

Comment: No. But I don’t think an extension matters in this simple case. For more complex cases, one can just assume no extensions are enabled when considered the legitimate output.

Comment: What I am referring to is the `head` element added, also the `x` is moved into `body`. I've deleted `data-gr-c-se-loaded`.

Comment: What do you mean by "I assume that javascript and CSS are not effective if they are in the HTML code"?

Comment: Browsers uses javascript and CSS to change the layout. I mean that the output that I need is just as if javascript and CSS are deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox parses the HTML into DOM using the HTML5 parsing algorithm. What you posted as "transformed code" is the serialization of the DOM that resulted from parsing.

Luckily, the HTML parsing is well-defined now, and there are implementations that run outside of the browser, for example https://html5-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

It doesn't have a CLI, so you'll have to add the code to read/write the file yourself:

```
from html5_parser import parse
from lxml.etree import tostring


root = parse("<html>x<body><div>abc</div></html>")
print(tostring(root))
```